# Dropbox API v2 to get the images/albums

Tags: http, dropbox-api

In **Dropbox API v1** I'm using "/1/metadata/dropbox" to get the total list of files.

In  **v2** I could not able to find the API to get the list of all images or files.

Can anyone please suggest me on how to get all the images/albums in API v2.

I'm working on https:// requests

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dropbox API v2, the equivalent functionality of API v1 /metadata can be found in [/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) and [/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)].

You can use /files/get_metadata to get information about any particular file or folder (except root itself.) You can use /files/list_folder[/continue] to get the listing of the contents of any folder.

It sounds like /files/list_folder[/continue] is what you're looking for in order to list the image files in a folder.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to display the list of all images of a user that are available in dropbox. For this i'm now doing /files/list_folder to get all the files and then /files/get_temporary_link to get the links of each files. 

But the process is becoming so slow that i have to call the **/files/get_temporary_link** API for each image available. Is there any way to **get all the temporary link of the images at once**.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/210091046-Get-temporary-links-of-multiple-files-at-once ]